# How do I switch from my app to map for directions?

Tags: xcode, maps, xcode4.2, direction

I'm programming a view based application in Xcode 4.2.
I am looking for some help to switch from my application, to the Apple map application.

So it should should by a push on a button switch to map, and start up the direction part and calculate the route to a given location.

Comment: This is a QA site and you are asking for a complete solution. Try asking simpler question, also providing a bit of code of your failed attempts.

Comment: and you should except answers if you wish people to answer you in the future

Answer (score 3):

You can open the map app using the following code:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];  
[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Rome"]];
```

you can also add parameters to it to get directions:
ll=: Stands for “latittude/longitude”

saddr=: The start, or “source,” address to use when generating driving directions.

daddr=: The end, or “destination,” address to use when generating driving directions.

t=: The type of map that will be displayed.

z=: The zoom level of the map that will be displayed.

**Therefore - if you like directions from Rome to Torino:**

```
 UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];  
    [app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Rome&saddr=rome&daddr=Torino"]];
```